# Loop with "for" and "if" and then a scatter-plot with different colors

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, scatter-plot

I would like a scatter plot with two different colors for different fields.

I have one table with `x1`, `x2`, `y3`. I make one scatter with `scatter(x1,x2,"o","filled")`, but I would like that colors were on the base of `y3`.

`y3` has values from 0 to 81. I would like that fields with values<10 were green, vice versa values>10 were red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional fourth input of [`scatter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) to specify color. That means you also need to define the third input, which specifies marker size:

```
x1 = randn(1,300);
x2 = randn(1,300);
y3 = rand(1,300)*81; % example data
markersize = 20; % or specify [], which causes default marker size to be used
scatter(x1, x2, markersize, y3<10, 'o', 'filled')
colormap([.8 0 0; 0 .8 0]) % red and green
```

[image]